# Jquery table with Link Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink, href

I use to following line for create the link button in td with append in jquery table .If i use this line the link button does not support to show in Blue color.**How to give the Style for that link button like the color as blue**?

```
.append($("<td/>", {'html': '<a href="#" id="id1" style="color:Blue" class="cls1" >Link Button</a>' }))
```

Comment: seems to be working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/2qPz9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like this,a Simple Way

```
.append($("<td/>").append($("<a/>",{"href":"#","html":"Link","id":"id1","style":"color:blue","class":"cls1" })))
```